# Dockerise ASP.NET Core app with Alpine image

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, asp.net-core, dotnet-publish

I want my dockerised ASP.NET Core 7 app based on [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) (not [ASP.NET Core Runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet)).

`MyApp.csproj` contains:

```xml
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-musl-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

`Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM alpine
```

But when I start a container, I get:

```
Error relocating /dist/MyApp: __cxa_pure_virtual: symbol not found
Error relocating /dist/MyApp: __cxa_pure_virtual: symbol not found
Error relocating /dist/MyApp: __cxa_pure_virtual: symbol not found
Error relocating /dist/MyApp: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /dist/MyApp: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /dist/MyApp: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
```

It works with the normal image (i.e. `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet`).

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview) imply that with the correct RID (`linux-musl-x64`), this should work. But obviously it's missing dependencies.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Alphine is a minimal image, I doubt it has .NET runtime installed... Probably need to install it. Or just use an official aspnet alpine base image

Comment: @ventsyv Thanks. If I understand the docs correctly, since I'm generating a single-file self-contained binary, that shouldn't be necessary; and targetting the musl RID means it *should* contain the necessary dependencies. If I add those APKs then I think all I'll be doing is upgrading the alpine image to a mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet image. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you tried setting IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract ? The documentation says only managed DLLs are bundled, maybe you are missing a native library?

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that one! I tried it and it doesn't solve the issue though.

Comment: You need an Alpine image with the .NET runtime dependencies, not just an empty Alpine image. Check the tags in the [dotnet-runtime-deps](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime-deps/) image. One of them will be Alpine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the list of Alpine packages that .NET requires at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/231835f7f8b1effdebbddea9521e34fa305e7459/src/runtime-deps/6.0/alpine3.18/amd64/Dockerfile#L11-L20. For .NET 6/7, those packages are the following:

- ca-certificates
- krb5-libs
- libgcc
- libintl
- libssl3
- libstdc++
- zlib

Make sure those packages are installed. These packages are necessary even when publishing as a self-contained app as the self-contained app only embeds the .NET runtime, not the native dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, straight from the horse's mouth! :-) I used the `runtime-deps` image and it worked. I did not set `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` so I assume it's unnecessary in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `runtime-deps:7.0-alpine` instead, ie:

```
FROM runtime-deps:7.0-alpine
```

or

```
FROM runtime-deps:6.0-alpine
```

The [.NET Runtime Dependencies](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime-deps/) image

> contains the native dependencies needed by .NET. It does not include .NET. It is for self-contained applications.

Alpine is a pretty slim distribution and doesn't contain many of the dependencies found on other distributions, like `libgcc`.

**Publish Directly to a Container**

.NET 7 added the ability to [publish directly to a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container). The linked docs show how this is done:

1. Add the `Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers` package to the project
2. Set the image name with the `ContainerImageName` property
3. Publish with `dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 /t:PublishContainer -c Release`

For self-published applications, the `runtime` image is used by default. It's possible to change this using the `ContainerBaseImage` property in `csproj` :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ContainerBaseImage>mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:7.0-alpine</ContainerBaseImage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could mark both as correct. The section "Publish Directly to a Container" was a revelation - I'm using ci/cd but for local dev builds that is going to be very useful. Thank you.